# MacBook wakes due to com.apple.alarm.user-visible-*

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have noticed my MacBook 16 M1 Pro is losing about 15% of battery overnight.

Running `pmset -g log | grep wake` shows:

```
2022-08-17 02:58:27 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=112 wakeAt=2022-08-17 03:00:20 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-seld_processing,378"]
2022-08-17 03:00:20 +0200 Assertions            PID 389(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009540 [System: No Assertions]
2022-08-17 03:00:25 +0200 Assertions            PID 389(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd00009540 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2022-08-17 03:02:19 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=114 wakeAt=2022-08-17 03:04:13 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-seld_processing,378"]
2022-08-17 03:04:13 +0200 Assertions            PID 389(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000095aa [System: PrevIdle]
2022-08-17 03:04:18 +0200 Assertions            PID 389(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd000095aa [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2022-08-17 03:06:12 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=113 wakeAt=2022-08-17 03:08:06 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-seld_processing,378"]
```

It seems `com.apple.alarm.user-visible-seld_processing,378` is causing all the mess. I could not find info on the seld process, nor how it isses the wake request. Do you know how to debug this further? Is there some way to prevent this?